# export files from mysql into archive through php

Tags: php, mysqli, tar

I am trying to add a functionality that will allow users to export all of their media from server's database(files are stored in mysql database).

This is the code that I am using to grab individual file from database:

```
$l=mysqli_fetch_assoc($R);//Raw data=['file'], File name=['name'] 
$xd = $l['file'];
$file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($l['name'],"."),1));
$ctype='';
switch( $file_extension ) {
    case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
    case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
    case "jpeg":
    case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
    case "webm": $ctype="video/webm"; break;
    default:
}
header('Content-type: ' . $ctype);
echo $xd;
```

ideally I would like to avoid creating a .tar file locally and sending a link to it. I remember creating tar files with C where I just put file size, file name and raw data and kept appending stuff in this format indefinitely, however I cannot find neither documentation of that method, nor any code that will allow me to do that in php. 
Am I at least going in the right direction, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you'll have to pull all rows of files inside your database of any files for that user. I'd store them all in an array so you can easily go through them with a `foreach`.

After that, I'd generate a random string of numbers and letters and create a folder with [`mkdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) in a folder somewhere. Let's call this your temporary folder. Then, you can use [`copy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) to copy the file to the temp folder.

After that, you can use [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) to execute a local command with the command line package of your choice to create a `.tar`. After that, you can copy the tar file back into the server area and delete the folder with [`rmdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php) so you can reduce clutter on your server.

> Am I going in the right direction with this?

Yes, if you wanted one file. You just need a virtual filesystem, such as a tar or zip file. An alternative would be to generate JS code with the PHP code so you can have it download all of the files, but a virtual filesystem takes less space (faster downloads) and is easier to work with if you want to move it out of your downloads file. It's your choice...